# I want the Mapquest OSM Geolocation to automatically show your current location but it's not?

Tags: geolocation, mapquest

Currently I have to press a on the top right-hand corner of the map to show my current location (it is the little person in the picture), is there a way for when the map load it automatically shows your location? I attached the code as well and a picture to explain. Thanks, I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.
 [image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.0.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=Kmjtd%7Cluua2qu7n9%2C7a%3Do5-lzbgq"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      /*An example of using the MQA.EventUtil to hook into the window load event and execute defined function
      passed in as the last parameter. You could alternatively create a plain function here and have it
      executed whenever you like (e.g. <body onload="yourfunction">).*/

      MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function() {

        /*Create an object for options*/
        var options={
          elt:document.getElementById('map'),        /*ID of element on the page where you want the map added*/
          zoom:13,                                   /*initial zoom level of map*/
          latLng:{lat:40.735383, lng:-73.984655},    /*center of map in latitude/longitude*/
          mtype:'osm'                                /*map type (osm)*/
        };

        /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/
        window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);

        MQA.withModule('geolocationcontrol', function() {
          map.addControl(
            new MQA.GeolocationControl()
          );
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='map' style='width:750px; height:280px;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any sort of commonality to where it *is* centering?

Comment: @andrewBarber it is centering around the location that the geolocater provided. If that makes sense, if not, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: So what is the problem of your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/api/MQA.GeolocationControl.html), you could try calling `activate` on the geolocation control after you create it.
If that does not cause a re-center/zoom then you may need to register a handler for the onLocate callback (also in the control). When your callback is called you can manually re-center/zoom the map.
Bear in mind that geolocation can be very inaccurate, doing it automatically will probably annoy users for whom that is the case.